# Excel VBA: how to solve Index and Match function type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel, indexing, match

I encounter error in index and match functions when the counter of date changes. I wrote a comment when I face with error. I uploaded a sample of my data if it needed. 
sample : http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00243748825638974221

here is the code :

```
Sub regionalAverage()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

' *** change the declaration here ***
Dim aname() As String
Dim rw As Variant
Dim col As Variant
Dim date_ini As Date
Dim date_fin As Date

'create WorkSheet

' *** add Redim here, so the index of the array will start from 1 ***
ReDim aname(1 To 2)

date_ini = #1/1/2008#
date_fin = #1/2/2008#
For j = 1 To 3
    For conteo = date_ini To date_fin
        For i = 1 To 2
            With Sheets(i)
               With Application

                    col = .Match(j, Worksheets(i).Range("F2:F23393"), 0)
                    rw = .Match(CLng(conteo),     Worksheets(i).Range("D2:D23393"), 0)
                   'error appeas here
                    aname(i) = .Index(Worksheets(i).Range("H2:H23393"), col, rw)  



               End With


            End With
        Next i

    '    computation
        area = 6.429571
        Sheets("Output").Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, j).Select
        colname = Split(ActiveCell(1).address(1, 0), "$")(0)
        Columns("" & colname & ":" & colname & "").Select
        Selection.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
         MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

        ActiveCell.Value = "=(SUM(" & aname(1) & "," & aname(2) & "))/" & area &  ""

    Next conteo
Next j

End Sub
```

When the date changes to 1/2/2008 I face with error, how can I solve it ?!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `Application.Match` and `Variant` data type, the error will not raise during the call to `.Match`, but those variables like `col` and `rw` will contain an `Error` type, if the value is not found in the search range/array.

This `Error` value will cause a `TypeMismatch` error when attempting to assign it to the `String` array, `aname()`.

So, you're halfway there, you just need error handling:

```
col = .Match(j, Worksheets(i).Range("F2:F23393"), 0)
rw = .Match(CLng(conteo), Worksheets(i).Range("D2:D23393"), 0)

If Not IsError(col) and Not IsError(rw) Then
    aname(i) = .Index(Worksheets(i).Range("H2:H23393"), col, rw)
Else
    ' Do something else if there was an error

End If
```

Alternatively, `Dim aName() as Variant`, but then you would probably need the error handling further/elsewhere in your code, to handle the error values you're putting in to the array.

I also observe that **`Index`** seems to be the source of the error, **and it is totally not needed here**, because:

`Index(range_object, row_num, col_num)` is literally the same as `range_object.Cells(row_num, col_num)`

So instead, I did:

```
aname(i) = CStr(Worksheets(i).Range("H2:H23393").Cells(rw, col).Value)
```

**NOTE:** I also assumed that you originally have `rw` and `col` in the wrong position for the `Index` function, and that `rw` is a *ROW* number and `col` is a *COLUMN* number.

Comment: Did you see the file uploaded ?! I did what you said but there is no improvement. Is there a way to solve this problem?! I am really in hurry.Thanks

Comment: Same error? On the same line (assigning to `anames(i)`?  Then try maybe:   `aname(i) = CStr(.Index(Worksheets(i).Range("H2:H23393"), col, rw))`  If that doesn't work, then please indicate what value of `col`, `rw`, and also what value exist in the cell coordinates given by `Range("H2:H23393").Cells(rw,col).Address`.

Comment: I used Cstr() but it does not work. I mentioned a link that a sample of my file uploaded there. I will be appreciate you if you please download it and check it yourself. I dont know what should I do to fix this problem.thanks

Comment: I don't want your file, what I want you to do is answer the questions I've asked: **1)** What is the value of `col`? **2)** what is the value of `rw`? and **3)** what is the value of `Range("H2:H23393").Cells(rw,col).Address`?

Comment: 1)for first loop of conteo : a)the value of col : 1 ,b)the value of rw: 1 , c)the value of  address is the value of found cell.2) for the second loop of conteo : a)the value of col : 1 ,b)the value of rw: 33 , c)the value of  address is type mismatch error

Comment: Can I have your email to share the file with you on dropbox !?

Comment: I was able to get it from the website without signing up. Now I do **not** observe an error when querying `Range("H2:H23393").Cells(rw,col).Address`. This doesn't produce an error, but the `Index` function does. Please confirm.

Comment: so should not I use the index function to get value of cell and put in an array "aname(i)" ?! whats your opinion ?!

Comment: I added to my answer, I am able to run the macro without any error now, making one small change to not use `Index` function.

Comment: Mr.Zemens Thank you for your consideration. I did what you said in With Application :   
                 `col = .Match(j, Worksheets(i).Range("F2:F23393"), 0)
                `rw = .Match(CLng(conteo), `Worksheets(i).Range("D2:D23393"), 0)
 `aname(i) = `CStr(Worksheets(i).Range("H2:H23393").Cells(rw, col).Value)
                `MsgBox aname(i)
                                                                                      but when the counter of j is 2 , the aname(i) is empty while I can find the value of cell manually. am I right ?

Comment: Perhaps you did need `CStr(Worksheets(i).Range("H2:H23393").Cells(col, rw).Value)` (in which case I would suggest you should rename your variables to avoid ambiguity), but apart from that, this is beyond the area where I can help, because I don't really know what you're trying to do (nor do I really care). This is now a logical/implementation problem, and that requires **you** to debug and fix the logic. I helped fix the obvious *error*, but I don't know what you're trying to do, nor how to make it "correct".

Comment: Thank you any way for your help.

Comment: What is the purpose of variables `col` and `rw`? What do those represent to you?

Comment: the purpose of col is to find a cell which contain an integer number based on "j" within Range("F2:F23393")  and the rw  to find a cell which contain a date based on "conteo" within Range("D2:D23393"). and after finding these I want to find the value of a cell that in its row has col and rw criteria. Thats it

Comment: Then based on that explanation, col and rw are independent of the loop. col will always == the value of j + 1, rw will always == the row where the searched date is first found. I think you need to go back to the drawing board, this program is not doing anything like what you think it is doing.

Comment: actually I want to change the value of "j"  from 1 to 32 and the value of "conteo" is changing from 1/1/2008 till 12/31/2009 . for simple running I reduce the bound of them. by the way, What is the fastest way to find a value of a cell with multiple criteria in a sheet ?!

Comment: Right, but because you're using `Match` function, it's always returning the *first* match for value `j`, no matter the date value, if j = 1, the match value == 2, etc.  Same thing with your date match, it's always going to return the row # of the *first* row where the date is found. I think you're better served doing the following: 1) Accept this answer (because it has solved the actual error which was in scope of your question and 2) Ask a new/separate question, explain fully what you're trying to do, what criteria you need, etc.

Comment: For example, `col` and `rw` are actually *both* returning a *row* index, but you're using them as though they represent a row and a column, in the `Cells` method (or previosly in the `Index` function. This is obviously wrong, but because I don't know what you're actually trying to do, or why you think that what you're doing is actually correct, I can't really help. You'll be better off with a new question, and maybe some other(s) can assist.

Comment: Ok thank you I accept it.I ask you Do you know a way to find a value of a cell with multiple criteria in a sheet ?!

Comment: Don't ask me. Ask a new question. (Yes, I know many ways to do this, but you need to ask a formal, well-explained question, and then perhaps I (or someone else) can assist you with that)